Bayesian updating as a Markov process
I am struggling with the following exercise (Exercise 10.5) from some notes on stochastic processes I am currently studying. It reads as follows.

Let $\theta:(\Omega,\mathcal{F})\to (\Theta,2^\Theta)$ be a random variable taking values in $\Theta:=\{\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_d\}$. Let $(\mathcal{G}_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ and define $\pi_t(\theta_i):=\mathbb{P}(\theta=\theta_i \mid \mathcal{G}_t)$. Let $\pi_t:(\Omega,\mathcal{G}_t)\to ([0,1]^d,\text{Bor}([0,1]^d))$ be the random vector $\pi_t=(\pi_t(\theta_1),\ldots,\pi_t(\theta_d))$. Prove that $(\pi_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a Markov process with respect to $(\mathcal{G}_t)_{t\geq 0}$.

There is also a hint that suggests to use the tower property for the conditional expectation but I cannot see how to use it in this setting.
I would like to know if this is a well-known (and true) result, if anyone knows how to prove it or knows about some references I can consult.
So far, I have only been able to prove a version of this theorem in the proper Bayesian setting (Exercise 10.4), i.e. assuming there are IID real-valued random variables $(X_j)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ with density functions $(f_{\theta_i}(x))_{i=1,...,d}$ (with respect to the Lebesgue measure) and priors $(\pi_0(\theta_i))_{i=1,\ldots,d}$ for $\theta$ such that $\mathcal{G}_n=\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ and $\pi_n(\theta_i)=\frac{\pi_0(\theta_i)f_{\theta_i}(X_1)\cdots f_{\theta_i}(X_n)}{\sum_{k=1}^d \pi_0(\theta_k) f_{\theta_k}(X_1)\cdots f_{\theta_k}(X_n)}$. The techniques I used to prove this particular case, however, do not seem to adapt to prove the more general statement.
